# ionic 2, content after background image doesn't cover all page

Tags: css, angular, ionic2

in my ionic 2 app,
I am trying to put a background image on a page.

The view contain slides, but I want the background to be fixed behind the slides.

It's almost working, except there's a black line at the top that doesn't seemed covered by the background.

In my page.scss file:

```
page-onboarding {

    .onboardingcontent, .onboardingcontent.content-md {
        // background-color: black;
        background-color: black !important;
        color: white;
    }
.onboardingcontent::after {
        content:"";
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        position: absolute;
        background-image: url(../img/LouisRomainSpeed.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center;
        opacity: 0.3;
        // z-index: 1;  
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you probably need to remove `padding` or `margin` from `.content-md` or `.onboardingcontent::after` class

Comment: Actually, padding and margin on those elements are all set to 0...

Answer (score 0):

Add the background-image to .scroll-content, like this:

```
.scroll-content {
    content:"";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(../img/LouisRomainSpeed.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

You can use it at `scroll-content` or `fixed-content`

Comment: The think is, I need a black layer below the image, because the image has opacity: 0.3

Comment: you can add the background-color to your ion-content, the scroll class is generated over it

Comment: ok I see, but if i put opacity to scoll-content, all my content is opaque